# Please help me in writing test class for my triggerclass

Tags: salesforce, apex, test-coverage

I have written a trigger to send email to particular email groups whenever a "Idea" record is created. I have to send emails to groups on the basis of combination of two multi-select picklist fields so I have added those combinations in "Custom Setting Data" and using it to fetch the email id's. Below is my code.

```
Public Class IdeaTriggerOperations1
{
Public Static Void NotifyBUonNewDiscussion1(List<Idea> IdeaIds)
{ 
    Set<String> CategoryNameSet = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> ProductNameSet = new Set<String>();

    //Set and clear emailAddresses
    String[] emailAddressess = new String[40];
    emailAddressess.clear();

    //Set Messaging
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(1);

    //Get Email Template Id
    EmailTemplate et = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE developerName = 'Idea_New_Discussion_Posted_BU'];


    For(Idea I : IdeaIds)
    {       
        String completeEmailList = '';                                  
        for(String str : I.Categories.split(';'))
        {
            CategoryNameSet.add(str);
            system.debug('-----------CategoryNameSet--------'+CategoryNameSet);
        } 
        If(I.Product__c != NULL)
        {
            for(String str1 : I.Product__c.split(';'))
            {
                ProductNameSet.add(str1);
                system.debug('-----------ProductNameSet--------'+ProductNameSet);
            }
        }
        Else{
            ProductNameSet = NULL; }

        // Generating Email List values for BU ... 
        If(i.Include_BU__c == True)
        { 
            If(!ProductNameSet.contains('Automata') && !ProductNameSet.contains('DRAM') && !ProductNameSet.contains('eMCP') && !ProductNameSet.contains('eMMC') && !ProductNameSet.contains('HMC') && !ProductNameSet.contains('MCP') && !ProductNameSet.contains('NAND') && !ProductNameSet.contains('NOR') && !ProductNameSet.contains('SSD') && !ProductNameSet.contains('N/A'))
                {
                    Idea_Custom_Setting__c nc = Idea_Custom_Setting__c.getValues('Product All');
                    completeEmailList += nc.BU_Email_Id__c+ ';' ;
                }

            List<Idea_Custom_Setting__c> IdeaEmails = Idea_Custom_Setting__c.getall().values();
            for(Idea_Custom_Setting__c m : IdeaEmails)
            {
                If(CategoryNameSet.contains(m.Category__c) && (ProductNameSet.contains(m.Product__c)||ProductNameSet==NULL))
                {
                    completeEmailList += m.BU_Email_Id__c + ';' ;
                } 
                If(CategoryNameSet.contains('Automotive') || CategoryNameSet.contains('Connected Home') || CategoryNameSet.contains('Consumer') || CategoryNameSet.contains('IMM'))
                If(ProductNameSet.contains(m.Combined_Category__c))
                {
                    completeEmailList += m.BU_Email_Id__c + ';' ;
                }               
            }  
        }//End of first IF statement

        // Generating Email List values for SME ...
        If( i.LastModifiedDate == i.CreatedDate)
        {         
            List<Idea_Custom_Setting_For_SME__c> SMECustSet = Idea_Custom_Setting_For_SME__c.getall().values();
            for(Idea_Custom_Setting_For_SME__c  N : SMECustSet)
            {
                If(CategoryNameSet.contains(N.Category_SME__c)){
                If(ProductNameSet.contains('N/A'))
                {
                    completeEmailList += N.SME_Email_Id__c + ';' ;
                }   }                 
                If(CategoryNameSet!=NULL && ProductNameSet.contains(N.Product_SME__c))
                {
                    completeEmailList += N.SME_Email_Id__c + ';' ;
                }
                If(!ProductNameSet.contains('Automata') && !ProductNameSet.contains('DRAM') && !ProductNameSet.contains('eMCP') && !ProductNameSet.contains('eMMC') && !ProductNameSet.contains('HMC') && !ProductNameSet.contains('MCP') && !ProductNameSet.contains('NAND') && !ProductNameSet.contains('NOR') && !ProductNameSet.contains('SSD') && !ProductNameSet.contains('N/A')){
                If(ProductNameSet.contains(N.Special_Value__c))
                {
                    completeEmailList += N.SME_Email_Id__c + ';' ;
                }}
            }
        }

       system.debug('-----------completeEmailList--------'+completeEmailList);
       for(String str2 : completeEmailList.split(';'))
       {
           emailAddressess.add(str2);
       }

        //Set Message Properties
        mail.setTargetObjectId(i.CreatedById);
        mail.setWhatId(i.Id);
        mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('SFDC Technical Discussion');
        mail.setToAddresses(emailAddressess);
        mail.setUseSignature(false);
        mail.setBccSender(false);
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

        // Update the Post to set the SME Notified field to TRUE
       If(i.Include_BU__c == True){
       List<Idea> nIdea = [SELECT Id, BU_Notified__c FROM Idea WHERE Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()];

            for (Idea o :nIdea){
                o.BU_Notified__c = True;
            }

            update nIdea; } 

    }
    // Send the email
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}}
```

**When I create an Idea record with my test class I always get error saying :**

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, IdeaTrigger1: execution of AfterInsert
>
> caused by: System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Invalid to address : : []
>
> Class.IdeaTriggerOperations1.NotifyBUonNewDiscussion1: line 114, column 1 Trigger.IdeaTrigger1: line 9, column 1: []

Comment: This is not valid Java code.  Not even remotely.

Comment: Hello Stephen,  Its is not a java code. It is Salesforce apex code.

Comment: I see ... some "helpful" person tagged it as Java when it isn't.  It would have helped if you have provided useful tags in the first place

Answer (score 0):

No Problem Stephen.
I am able to solve my issue now.

I was not using (SeeAllData=true) in class which was causing the issue when I was referring community id while creating Idea record. Due to this no records were getting inserted.

Thanks!